# I'm trying to bind the files into other form also make validation empty file in fileselect

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone help me with my script, i want to bind photo with another form, this is my code for validating a photo

```
if(isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == 0){
    $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
    $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
    $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
    // Verify file extension
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

    // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
    $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

    // Verify MYME type of the file
    if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $newfilename);
            $photo = $filename;

    } else{
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again."; 
    }
    } 
    // No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
    $input_photo = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];
    if($_FILES['photo']['size'] == 0) 
    { $photo_err = "Please Select an Image.";
    } else {
    $photo = $input_photo;
    }
```

And thi is my bind code

```
if(empty($name_err) && empty($address_err) && empty($salary_err)){
    // Prepare an insert statement
    $asd = ($_SESSION['username']) ;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO employees (name, address, salary, code, photo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, '$asd', '$newfilename')";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_name, $param_address, $param_salary, $param_photo);

        // Set parameters
        $param_name = $name;
        $param_address = $address;
        $param_salary = $salary;
        $param_photo = $photo;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: index2.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }
```

Also the error is mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\coba\create.php on line 90
Something went wrong. Please try again later.

```
$name = $address = $salary = $photo = "";

$name_err = $address_err = $salary_err = $photo_err= "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_name, $param_address, $param_salary, $param_photo);
```

The "sss" tells it you will be binding three strings. You then provide four variables. There are only three empty spots in your query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO employees (name, address, salary, code, photo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, '$asd', '$newfilename')";
```

... you are also including two variables in a way that helps defeat the purpose of bound parameters. You should fix both of these at once like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO employees (name, address, salary, code, photo) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
...
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $param_name, $param_address, $param_salary, $asd, $newfilename);
```

Please note that I'm guessing at the variable assignments, so you should check and make sure, but this is intended to convey the concept.

Comment: Thx for the explanation it work for me, i change into you code